# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when using arcgis javascript in node.js

Tags: javascript, security, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I meet a problem when using ARCGIS JavaScript(version 4.9) to handle map data.
My environment is node.js with express.
the following is my code snippet:

```
esriConfig.request.trustedServers.push("https://XXX.XXX.XX.118:3070");
...
newBasemap = new TileLayer({
                                            url: "https://arcgis.tpgos.gov.taipei/arcgis/rest/services/ED/GD_Plain_Service/MapServer",
                                            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                                            spatialReference: { wkid: 102443 }
                                        });
 if (newBasemap != undefined) {
                                        map.add(newBasemap);
                                    }/
```

and this cause an error message.
The Error message show [Access to image ...from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]

And I found the image element not insert into map object, it is reject when fetching then throw the error. So I use following codes to catch event before image loading data, but it is still invalid.

```
var observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to handle mutations
function handleMutations(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        console.log("call event");
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            // Handle added nodes (images)
            $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('img').attr("crossorigin", "true");
        }
    });
}

// Create a new MutationObserver with the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutations);

// Start observing the target node (divmap) and the specified configuration
observer.observe(document.getElementById('divmap'), observerConfig);
```

Does any one know how to solve this problem, any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have control of the host server (`https://xxxxxxxxx` in your post)?

Comment: Assuming the origins are different, then, yes, your browser request is subject to CORS

Comment: none, I have no control on this map server(https://arcgis.tpgos.gov.taipei/arcgis/rest/services/ED/GD_Plain_Service/MapServer). I am subject to CORS, and after using version 4.9, using esriConfig.request.trustedServers.push("xxx.xxx.50.118:3070")，still into another cors problem. the option of arcgis javascript seems very complicate, and I need assistant to handle this.

Comment: **Please clarify what your execution environment is.** In your title, you mention that you're "*using arcgis javascript in node.js*", but CORS-related errors should never appear when making requests from a Node.js (server-side) execution environment, since CORS is a web browser-specific security concept.

Comment: my environment is node.js with express using ejs to build web page, and after using version 4.9, using esriConfig.request.trustedServers.push("xxx.xxx.50.118:3070")，still into another cors problem(access to image error..cors...). I have tried many methods, but still invalid.Thanks.